# Windows: How to stop buffering of redirected Stdout using CreateProcess

Tags: windows, winapi, process, stdout, win32-process

I am using pipes to get redirected stdout output from a command line executable. Unfortunately I don't get any output until the process has completed. The executable outputs progress status as it runs and this is what I would like to parse.

```
BOOL RunCmd( char  *pCmd, 
             char  *pWorkingDir, 
             int    nWaitSecs, 
             BOOL   fRegImport, 
             DWORD *pdwExitCode )
{
  BOOL                fSuccess = TRUE;
  STARTUPINFO         si;
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sFileSecurity;
  ZeroMemory( &sFileSecurity, sizeof( sFileSecurity ) );
  sFileSecurity.nLength        = sizeof( sFileSecurity );
  sFileSecurity.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

  HANDLE hReadPipe  = NULL;
  HANDLE hWritePipe = NULL;

  fSuccess = CreatePipe( &hReadPipe, &hWritePipe, &sFileSecurity, 0 );
  SetHandleInformation( hReadPipe, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0 ); 

  ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
  ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
  si.cb          = sizeof( si );
  si.dwFlags     = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
  si.hStdOutput  = hWritePipe;
  si.hStdError   = hWritePipe;
  si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

  int rc;

  // Start the child process. 
  rc = CreateProcess( NULL, // No module name (use command line). 
                      pCmd, // Command line. 
                      NULL,             // Process handle not inheritable. 
                      NULL,             // Thread handle not inheritable. 
                      TRUE,
                      CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
                      NULL,             // Use parent's environment block. 
                      pWorkingDir,      // Working folder
                      &si,              // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure.
                      &pi );            // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.


  if( ! rc )
    return FALSE;

  // Wait until child process exits.
  DWORD dwWaitResult;
  DWORD dwTimeStart = ::GetTickCount();
  DWORD dwTimeNow;

  #define BUFSIZE 4096  

  DWORD dwRead = 0; 
  DWORD dwAvail;
  CHAR  chBuf[ BUFSIZE ];
  BOOL  bSuccess = TRUE;

  for( ;; )
  {
    dwTimeNow    = ::GetTickCount();
    dwWaitResult = ::WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, ONE_SECOND );
    dwRead       = 0;

    for( dwAvail = 0; PeekNamedPipe( hReadPipe, 0, 0, 0, &dwAvail, 0 ) && dwAvail; dwAvail = 0 )
    {
      dwRead = 0;
      ReadFile( hReadPipe, chBuf, min( BUFSIZE, dwAvail ), &dwRead, NULL );

      if( dwRead > 0 )
      {
        FILE *op = fopen( "c:\\REDIR.OUT", "a" );

        if( op )
        {
          fwrite( chBuf, 1, dwRead, op );
          fclose( op );
        }
      }
    }

    if( dwWaitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
    {
      DWORD dwExitCode;
      GetExitCodeProcess( pi.hProcess, &dwExitCode );

      if( pdwExitCode )
        (*pdwExitCode) = dwExitCode;

      break;
    }

    if( dwWaitResult == WAIT_TIMEOUT )
    {
      if( dwTimeNow - dwTimeStart < (DWORD)( ONE_SECOND * nWaitSecs ) )
        continue;
      else
      {
        fSuccess = FALSE;
        break;
      }
    }

    fSuccess = FALSE;
    break;
  }

  CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
  CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
  CloseHandle( hReadPipe );
  CloseHandle( hWritePipe );

  return fSuccess;
}
```

The PeekNamedPipe() call is called every second and dwAvail is zero every time until the process completes.

How do I get output from the process sooner? When running the process from the console, I see progress output as it goes. The process will be using "\r" in it's output to display a percentage at the start of the same line.

Comment: The buffering is in the other app, not in the OS. You will have to modify the process you are launching to tell it to disable buffering.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks - that was my biggest fear. We don't have the source for that. Come to think of it, I have seen it buffering its output when we've run it as Visual Studio "external tool" as well. You'd think if CMD.exe is capable of displaying all of its progress updates then a wrapper program would be able to do the same thing.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yep, the following link describes the problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/190351

Comment: That's because cmd connects stdout to the console. Most apps detect whether stdout is connected to a console and buffer if not. This is internal app logic the OS has no control over.

Answer (score 2):

Note: My answer only deals with executables compiled using MSVC.

The buffering policy is coded inside Microsoft C Runtime (CRT) Library. You can learn the details [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16163/Real-Time-Console-Output-Redirection). This article suggests using console handles and manipulate console buffers to receive unbuffered output.

However, there's an undocumented feature inside Microsoft C Runtime to inherit file handles with some internal flags directly from its parent process using `lpReserved2` and `cbReserved2` fields of `STARTUPINFO` structure. You can find the details in the crt source code provided by Microsoft Visual Studio. Or search for something like `posfhnd` on GitHub.

We can exploit this undocumented feature to provide a pipe handle and specify `FOPEN | FDEV` flags to the child process, to fool the child process treat that pipe handle the same way as a `FILE_TYPE_CHAR` handle.

I have a working [Python3 script](https://gist.github.com/zhangyoufu/be36035e94b8c0dcb1239a3c8b07a3b1) to demonstrate this method.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified C/C++ version of the answer by @youfu.

```
STARTUPINFO si;
int nh = 2;
si.cbReserved2 = (WORD)(sizeof(int) + (nh *
                          (sizeof(char) + sizeof(HANDLE))));

si.lpReserved2 = (LPBYTE) calloc(si.cbReserved2, 1);

*((UNALIGNED int *)(si.lpReserved2)) = nh;

unsigned char* posfile = (unsigned char *)(si.lpReserved2 + sizeof(int));

UNALIGNED HANDLE* posfhnd = (UNALIGNED HANDLE *)(si.lpReserved2 + sizeof(int) +
          (nh * sizeof(unsigned char)));

unsigned char FOPEN = 0x01;
unsigned char FDEV  = 0x40;
*posfile = FOPEN | FDEV;
posfile++;
*posfile = FOPEN | FDEV;

*posfhnd = child_stdin_rd;
posfhnd++;
*posfhnd = child_stdout_wr;
```

-Suraj